# Are Generics A Good Way To Resolve Overloaded Methods?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overloading

two minutes ago, i came up with an idea to select overloaded methods with an interface.
we currently using [UIP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817680.aspx) from Microsoft application blocks.
they use an OnEnterTask-Method with one object parameter in each controller.
but this leads to an type-checking mess.

so i came up with the idea to use an interface to select the correct method:

```
interface IAcceptTaskArguments<TInputArguments> where TInputArguments : InputArguments
{
   void OnEnterTask(TInputArguments arguments);
}
```

is it a good practice to do something like this to avoid that typechecking-mess?

thank you guys.

Comment: Why not just cast to the type that matches the signature of the method?  It's going to be just as verbose.

Comment: Could you tell us what UIP is and show us the OnEnterTask method that MSFT wrote in code?

Comment: a controller can be entered with different inputargumenttypes and the calls to OnEnterTask are very generic.because of the configuration system of uip

Comment: another link to download it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649689.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use **generics** versus **method overloading**. When overloading is required I prefer to pass an instance of a class (or an interface) having all the parameters, then checking for *default customized values* for each parameter, if the value is the default it means no value was given for such parameter.

With **version 4.0 of Microsoft's Framework**, it is easier to use generics because, there is some keyword named **dynamic** by which you can call a static method from generic methods:

```
namespace Layer.Logic
{
    public class EntityObjectCommands : LogicContextBase, IEntityObjectCommands
    {
        public Tresult Get<Tcommand, Tresult>(Tcommand command) where Tcommand : ICommandGet
        {
            Tresult result = default(Tresult);
            DBEntityObjectCommands dbfactory = new DBEntityObjectCommands(GetDataServiceParam(dbserver));
            result = dbfactory.Get<Tcommand, Tresult>(command);     
            return result;
        }
    }
}
namespace Layer.Data
{
    public class DBEntityObjectCommands : IEntityObjectCommands
    {
        public Tresult Get<Tcommand, Tresult>(Tcommand command) where Tcommand : ICommandGet
        {
          Tresult result = default(Tresult);
          OleDbCommandInfo commandInfo = DBCommandProvider<Tcommand>.Get(command);

          //-- implement logic to use [commandInfo] ...........

          return result;
        }       
    }   
    public static class DBCommandProvider<Tcommand> where Tcommand : ICommand
    {
        public static OleDbCommandInfo Get(Tcommand command)
        {   
            return DBCommands.Get( (dynamic)command );
        }
    }   
}
```